# JavaScript: how to create a clone 2-D array from a certain 2-D array

Tags: javascript

Could you help me copy a 2-D array when you use JavaScript?
Currently, I understand that the assign like 'array2 = array1' does not work, because both arrays will have the same value when either of them let its value change.
So, I used Object.create() so that two 2-d arrays would be totally different.

```
console.log("Hiiiii");

let randnum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );

// Create a shift-jis-loading csv instance
let csv = new XMLHttpRequest();
csv.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=shift_jis");
 
// Open a csv file
csv.open("GET", "./csvfile/Word_List_1.csv", false);
 
// In case of failures of csv loading
try {
  csv.send(null);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
 
// Define an array
let csvArray = [];
 
// Process toward an Array csvArray
let lines = csv.responseText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
 
// Proceed with each line
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
  let cells = lines[i].split(",");
  if (cells.length != 1) {
    csvArray.push(cells);
  }
}

// Remove the last value of each row
csvArray.map((row)=>{
  row.pop()
})
 
// コンソールに配列を出力
// console.log(csvArray[randnum][0]);
// console.log(csvArray[randnum][1]);

console.log(csvArray);


console.log("before copy");
console.log(csvArray[0][0]);

// Copy the csvArray
let cloneArray = Object.create(csvArray);

// Check whether each value will be different
cloneArray[0][0]="testMan";

// The result is that both the value is the same: "testMan"
console.log(csvArray[0][0]);
console.log(cloneArray[0][0]);
```

I would be very grateful if you could kindly show an example of copying 2-d arrays.

[image]

Here are pictures and codes.

Comment: In the console part of the picture, the last two "testMan" are for the code: console.log(csvArray[0][0]);
console.log(cloneArray[0][0]);

Comment: [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone).

Comment: Thank you Andy. Your information went to my great help.

Answer (score 2):

The new way to create a deep copy of JS objects is `structuredClone`:

```
let cloneArray = structuredClone(csvArray);
```

But the old way of using `JSON` is still faster since `structuredClone` has some overhead. If you don't need features like keeping cross linked objects (which is your case with CSV):

```
let cloneArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(csvArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways that come to my mind. Two of them were already mentioned by @alexander-nenashev:

1. Using `structuredClone`. This is very powerful function but only makes sense for complex non-JSON structures (e.g. Sets, Maps etc.)
2. Using `JSON.parse` + `JSON.stringify`. This is quite fast and simple way of doing deep copy but it's restricted to JSON-like structures - Arrays and Objects.
3. Doing manual copy. Although this is quite cumbersome for any non trivial object, for simple arrays it would be the fastest approach.

```
const newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach((row, i) => {
  newArray.push([]);
  row.forEach((cell) => newArray[i].push(cell));
});
```